# Why is Music not allowed at Jewish Funerals?

Tags: talmud-gemara, death, music, sitting-shiva

When my mother died several decades ago, a childhood friend and I performed her favorite Yiddish song, "Dona Dona," at her funeral. Being raised in non-observant families we were surprised when a professional mourner (not an attendee) complained to us afterward that music was not allowed at Jewish funerals.

More recently, I happened to do some research on the use of the flute in ancient Jewish mourning rituals and discovered that music had once been not only allowed but virtually required. Even G-d reportedly used music to mourn, or at least to represent mourning:

> My heart moans for Moab like a flute, and my heart moans like a flute
> for the people of Kir-heres; for the riches they gained have perished.
> (Jer. 48:35-36)

The [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12180-pipe) adds:

> Among the later Jews flute-playing was considered so essential at
> funerals that even the poorest would not do without it.

But today, [funerary music is discouraged](https://rfhr.com/jewish-funeral/), even outright prohibited.

So what happened? Is the current prohibition based on the Talmud, and if so where? Any information about the historical circumstances of this development (destruction of the Temple for example) would be appreciated. Also, how universal is the prohibition against funerary music? Do some traditions (Reform, Hasidic, etc.) allow it?

Comment: It is not obvious that this is prohibited, some *chassidic* masters asked for *chassidic* tunes to be sung at their funerals.

Comment: I'm curious what a "professional mourner" is?

Comment: @MosesSupposes https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/understanding-grief/201802/professional-mourners-ancient-tradition in the Mishna's time, they would hire women to sing sad songs at the funeral, to get everyone to cry more. There were notes about how on a regular day there would be call-and-response singing as well as clapping, to amplify the effect, but on quasi-holidays they toned it down with just singing in unison. Here's how it's done today in Ghana: https://www.odditycentral.com/news/ghanas-professional-mourners-get-paid-to-cry-at-strangers-funerals.html

Comment: And the commentaries kind of shrug and say "hm yeah today that would never fly" ... or "gee didn't the Talmud also say that women's singing could be inappropriate? I guess given the mood at a funeral that wasn't an issue" ... honestly it's kind of murky -- it used to very much be done, and now it is not.

Comment: The real point here, though, is that whatever music was done then was intended to make everyone cry more. A funeral isn't the place for a feel-good concert. Then again, they say Big Bird singing "It's Not Easy Being Green" at Jim Henson's funeral had everyone in tears. Emotions are complicated! (I think over the years, having lost the mimetic tradition of "the way we've always done funeral music", the Orthodox world has decided it's easiest to say "just no music at all" vs. "let's call it case-by-case.") Probably happened sometime in the shift from Iraq to France, sometime between 600 and 1000

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/579208/jewish/Are-Songs-Sung-at-Jewish-Funerals.htm

Comment: @MosesSupposes a professional mourner is someone who gets paid attend funerals or otherwise help (sitting shiva?) when the person doesn't have enough relatives. But after googling the term, I may need to ask another question, since I could find very little. What I know for certain is that my Aunt said "don't worry about it, she's a professional mourner who works here and happened to overhear your song, not someone who knew your mom at all." I assumed this meant she was part of the staff of the cemetery, but probably she was a free-lancer.